# ReactJS: Returning div or span from map on Indexed Collections like Int32Array and Float32Array returns 0s and NaNs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

1. Create a simple react app
2. Add a Int32Array with some values. (Here we'll take [12, 4, 15, 6])
3. Use map on the variable and return a div or span with value inside

```js
let intArray = new Int32Array([12, 4, 15, 6]);
```

```
<div>
  <div>IntArray {intArray.join(", ")} Below</div>
    {
        intArray.map((el, index) => {
        return(
            <div>
            {index}: {el}
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3xfzstb5/

#### Output

```
0000
```

#### Expected Output

```
12
4
15
6
```

This happens when return for map wrapped in div or span. Is there something very basic that I am (or React is) missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you console the `intArray` you would find that it's been transferred to an Object

```
Int32Array {0: 12, 1: 4, 2: 15, 3: 6}
```

For such kind of Object, we can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to replace Array `map()`

```
{Object.values(intArray).map((el, index) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {index}: {el}
    </div>
  );
})}
```

---

[image]

---

[image: Edit sharp-lederberg-1nxkz]